# Read contacts while android application installing

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am developing one android application ,I want to read user contacts while app installing and store it to my database ,please give some ideas and codes
Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can read device contact by using [Retrieving a List of Contacts](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html)

Here is sample example [Android Contacts Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/provider/android-contacts-example/)

Then store that contact list in database using [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Here sample example is  [Database](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e14021/insert-delete-and-view-functionalists-in-a-database-in-andr/)